# How to solve inequalities with multiple variables usig Sympy?

Tags: sympy, inequality

I got to solve with Sympy the following inequality $t < 4x^2 + 2xy + 8y^2$ with |x| < 6 and |y| < 5 but I don't now how to do so.

I tried with solve and solve_rational_inequalities

```
from sympy import solve
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.solvers import solve (respectively solve_rational_inequalities)

x,y,z = symbols('x y z')
solve(z < 4*x**2 + 2*x*y + 8*y**2,(abs(x)<6,abs(y)<5,z))
```

but I have always an error message.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: What do you mean by "solve" here?  The usual meaning of solving an inequality for `t` would be to isolate `t` on one side of the inequality, but here it's already isolated, so I'm not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please also post the error message

Comment: SymPy won't solve multivariable inequalities. See discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sympy/solving$20constraints%7Csort:date/sympy/AYcts9KwswI/9YekFNPfCQAJ)